# Highcharts: How can I create a table of strings that can also export as an image?

Tags: highcharts

I'm able to create a highcharts table of numerical data. However, I would like to create a table where it displays text 'as well as', being able to export the table as a .png, .jpg, etc

Here is my jsfiddle of the table:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/eblanks/vm813fyo/36/`
```

Comment: Hi @eblanks, Could yoy describe the problem more precisely? Where do you want to display the text?

Comment: hello @ppotaczek i'm trying to display the 'text' field instead of the 'y' value. So fore instance,


data: [{ text: 'Row 2 Column 1', y: 7}, {text: 'Row 2 Column 2', y: 8}, {text:'Row 3 Column 3', y:9}, {text: 'Row 4 Column 4', y:10}, {text: 'Row 4 Column 5', y: 11}, {text: 'Row 5 Column 6', y: 12}]


I want to display: 'Row 2 Column1', 'Row 2 Column 2', ... instead the table is display '7', '8', '9', etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keys` option:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        keys: ['text'],
        ...

    }
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vx67yLfw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys